# Dynamically Invoke an object a few levels down in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic, return

```
var myObj = {
    bar_foo : "test",
    bar : {
       foo : "hi there";
         },
    foo : {
          bar : {
                 foo: "and here we go!"
                 }
           }
     }
```

How to get this:

```
var arr = [["bar", "foo"], ["foo", "bar", "foo"]];
```

to return this:

```
myObj["bar"]["foo"];
myObj["foo"]["bar"]["foo"];
```

`arr` can be any length so that it traverses the object.

So we know that we can dynamically call an object's value like so:

var normally = myObj["bar_foo"];

where `normally` would equal `"test"`

But this technique assumes we know how deep the traversing goes here.

What I'm trying to do is retrieve an objects value by providing an array

`["bar", "foo"]`

which would essentially be the same thing as:

`myObj["bar"]["foo"];`

The reason why I'm doing this is because I'm creating a new object based on the values I want from arr.

so the end result would be:

`arr_new = myObj.someMethod(arr);`

where `arr_new` is:

`arr_new : ["hi there", "and here we go!"];`

I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I feel like your setting me up to bash me here Jeff, I know these forums pretty well ;) But I'm going to assume your just being a nice guy. yes I have a long complicated method that traverses, but was wondering if someone was more clever than me and could possibly point to a method in jQuery or js that does this for you.

Comment: Not at all a setup - I am in fact a nice guy. It just helps to get a response when you show what you've done so far rather than "how do I do this?" It would be worth posting what you have so far, and I'm sure people will help to improve.

Comment: Okay, let me clean it up a bit because it's part of a bigger jQuery plugin and I'll pop it in. And please forgive me for assuming, but I'm sure you know these forums too ;)

Comment: I don't understand the result. Are you looking for a function that returns an Array with the desired values?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're expecting the result to be? Since you're listing statements, are you wanting to generate strings of code to `eval()` later? Or were those meant to represent gathering the values found by iterating each key list?

Comment: ...and how will we know if we were more clever than you if you don't show us  your attempt?

Comment: Please review the new question. Thank you guys!

Comment: output is invalid syntax, not sure if you want array or array of objects

Comment: Sorry, good catch. I've been writing literal objects all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```
function getObjValue( arr, obj){
    var tmp=obj;
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        tmp=tmp[arr[i]];
    }
    return tmp
}

alert( getObjValue( arr[1],myObj)); // "and here we go!"
```

To create array of values:

```
var result=arr.map(function(subArr){
   return  getObjValue(subArr,myObj);
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ahnD4/2/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Underscore (or can use native JS `map` and `reduce`), try this:

```
var myObj = {
  bar: {
    foo: "hi there"
  },
  foo: {
    bar: {
      foo: "and here we go!"
    }
  }
};

var arr = [
  ["bar", "foo"],
  ["foo", "bar", "foo"]
];

function deepProp(arr, obj) {
  return _.reduce(arr, function(memo, val) {
    return memo[val];
  }, obj);
}

var deepProps = _.map(arr, function(deepArray) {
  return deepProp(deepArray, myObj);
});

console.log(deepProps); // => ["hi there", "and here we go!"]
```

There may be a more elegant solution; this was a quick hack. Seems to do pretty much what you want though! :P

Comment: For the reduce, you may want to do `return memo && (val in memo) ? memo[val] : null;` in order to handle the circumstance where the keys did not exist.

Comment: @cookiemonster Yep, that's pretty much why this is just a quick hack. It assumes the nested array is 100% accurate in it's knowledge of the object structure. Pretty simple to fix though, as you've shown.

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.prototype.someMethod = function (arr) {

  function a (obj, array){
    var res = obj[array.splice(0, 1)[0]];
    if (typeof res === 'object' && array.length) {
      return a(res, array);
    }else{
      return res;
    }
  }
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result.push(a(this, arr[i]));
  }
  return result;
};
```

JSBin >> [Demo](http://jsbin.com/abIGucaX/3/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

I made a fiddle showing a possible answer, without using libraries:

http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/6s9HY/2/

```
var traverseObject = function(obj, arr) {
    var results = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var tempObj = obj;

        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            tempObj = tempObj[arr[i][j]];
        }

        results.push(tempObj);
    }
    return results;
};
```

Of course, this assumes that the parameters will always be valid, but validation checks can be added.